# How do I call Kendo treeview (server data binding type) after success of AJAX post?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

This is the Kendo treeview I'm using to bind

```
Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                .Name("TreeViewTemplateBiding")
                 .Events(events => events
            .Select("onSelect"))
                        .BindTo((IEnumerable<OrgChart.Models.NodeViewModel>)ViewBag.Tree, (Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.NavigationBindingFactory<TreeViewItem> mappings) =>
                           {
                               mappings.For<OrgChart.Models.NodeViewModel>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, node) =>
                               {
                                   item.Id = node.Id;
                                   item.Text = node.Title;
                                   //item.Url = "/Organizational/Chart/" + node.Id;
                                   //item.Expanded = node.Expanded;
                               })
                       .Children(node => node.Children));
                           })
    )
```

And AJAX post is used to get onselect node data and sending it to controller to get its children.

```
<script>
function onSelect(e) {
    alert("hi");
    var data = this.text(e.node);
    alert(data);
     var a =  data.split("- ").pop(); 
    alert(a);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Chart", "Organizational")',
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { a : a },
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("sending");
            process(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {  }
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    });
}
</script>
```

So after successful posting I need to call again Kendo tree.

Comment: You can possibly save some time by using the HierarchicalDataSource here if all your nodes have a unique id.

Comment: That HierarchicalDataSource on the TreeView will make a callback to the endpoint to get the children for the selected node, if not loaded.

Comment: ok how can i achieve that, plz help me with this

Comment: Pro tips for posting: please refrain from adding "please help me" in your comments and in your questions. We know you need help, and adding notes to this effect explicitly may be interpreted as a form of begging. Furthermore, please try to use real words rather than txtspk such as "plz". If whole words are too much trouble to type, Stack Overflow may not be for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an exact answer, however this is one way to let the `HierarchicalDataSource` do some work for you.

NOTE : This is pseudo-code. There is no type checking of validation and splits the input to get nodetype/nodeid.

**Simple TreeView Class**

```
  public class TreeViewItem
    {
        //Collection item returned in he Hierarchical search
        public TreeViewItem()
        {
            CanSelect = true;
        }

        public string NodeID{get;set;}
        public string NodeText{ get; set; }        
        public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
        public bool CanSelect { get; set; }
        public string NodeImage { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
 public ActionResult PerformHierarchicalSearch(string NodeID)
 {
     //This action returns the data as List<TreeViewItem> in json format to the browse view.
     //The view is configured as three treeviews that use the Kendo Hierarchical datasource
     //Requires a NodeID and HasChildren each time an item is expanded it returns a NodeID 
     //On the intial load NodeID is null so return all items for the root

    //When a treeview item is expanded it calls this action but this time the node ID will be in <ENTITY_ID>:<USER_TYPE> format ex: 10038:40
    //We split that out and determine what to load. For example all children of a selected parent.

    string[] kludge = NodeID.Split(':');
    int nodeID = Convert.ToInt32(kludge[0]);
    int nodeType = Convert.ToInt32(kludge[1]);

    List<TreeViewItem> items = new List<TreeViewItem>();

     switch (nodeType)
     {
         case 1:
             List<Type1> type1List = new Type1Controller().GetType1(nodeID).ToList();
             foreach (Type1 type1 in type1List)
                 items.Add(new TreeViewItem
                 {
                     NodeID = type1.TypeID.ToString() + ":1",
                     NodeText = type1.TypeName,
                     HasChildren = true,
                     NodeImage = "TYPE1"
                 });
             break;
         case 2:
             List<Type2> type1List = new Type2Controller().GetType2(nodeID).ToList();
             foreach (Type2 type1 in type2List)
                 items.Add(new TreeViewItem
                 {
                     NodeID = type2.TypeID.ToString() + ":2",
                     NodeText = type2.TypeName,
                     HasChildren = true,
                     NodeImage = "TYPE2"
                 });
             break;
     }
     if (items.Count == 0 )
         items.Add(new TreeViewItem { NodeID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), NodeText = "No Data", HasChildren = false, CanSelect = false, NodeImage = "" });

     return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
}
```

**Code Behind**

```
<div id="treeview1" class="parentItem"></div>

<script id="treeview-navlink" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    #if (item.CanSelect != 'null' && item.CanSelect==true)  { #
        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Icons/16/Soft/")#: item.NodeImage #.png'+ alt='#: item.NodeImage #'/> <a href='\#' id= '#: item.NodeID #' class='entity-link' >#: item.NodeText #</a>    
    #}else{#
        <span class='dimText'>#: item.NodeText #</span>    
    #}# 
</script>



 <script type="text/javascript">

    var treeLoaded = false;

    ds1 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("PerformHierarchicalSearch","Search")' ,
                dataType: "json",
                data: addData1
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "NodeID",
                hasChildren: "HasChildren"
            }
        }
    });

    function addData1(d) {
        var treeview = $('#treeview1').data('kendoTreeView');
        if (treeLoaded === true)
            return { NodeID: d.NodeID};
        treeLoaded = true;
        return { };
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#treeview1").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: ds1,
            dataTextField: "NodeText",
            template: kendo.template($("#treeview-navlink").html())
        });
    });

</script>
```